# how to selcet item from NavigationView

Tags: android

i want when i Click on item in my Navigation go to another ....Activity .....

but i faced problem i cant solve it and i reed a lot of topic here

is it Important to use any thing from XML..?
and whats the Different between Navigation View and Fragment?

this is my XML

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/draw"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"

                    android:background="#ab9797"
                    app:menu="@menu/men">


                </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


            </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

this is my Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView1;
NavigationView navigationView;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {


        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {

                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.shark) {
                    Intent newActivity00 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main18Activity.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity00);

                }
                drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.draw);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;

            }

        });

    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}













    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qas);
    textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

open app agian   ......
thanks all .....

Comment: `the app closer when it just run` - How so? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: sory if tis not clear i edit

Comment: Do you want to start a fragment or an activity??

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your `onCreate()` method, you have this snippet of code:

```
textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qas);
textView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ...
});
```

The XML layout you posted does not contain a view with the id `qas`, which means that the first line will assign a `null` value to `textView1`. Therefore, the second line will throw a `NullPointerException` when you try to call `textView1.setOnClickListener()`.

There are two solutions: delete this snippet from `onCreate()` or add a `<TextView>` tag with an id of `qas` to your XML layout file.

Comment: i didnot post this part ... the problem with the Naviagtion

Comment: @MrwanYassinALGANAD what do you mean you "did not post this part"? It's in your question; just scroll to the bottom of the posted code.